# How to Show google map?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I am trying to show a google map using the following code:

```
<embed height="400" width="600" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=110069293083852065946.00047e2506156dd8d127b&amp;ll=27.727526,85.310855&amp;spn=0.021197,0.038581&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=00047e251edcecb28ba7c&amp;output=embed">
```

It works fine and shows the map correctly in my chrome browser by it shows missing plugin in firefox browser.

What is wrong with this? Is the code itself wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an iframe, not sure where that embed tag came from.

```
<iframe width="400" height="600" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=110069293083852065946.00047e2506156dd8d127b&amp;ll=27.727526,85.310855&amp;spn=0.021197,0.038581&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=00047e251edcecb28ba7c&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: The chances of that are slim... it will only happen with overly paranoid users of overly paranoid browsers. Nobody with any sense disables iframes.

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty of documentation on this:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

I've never seen it use embed, usually you just create it using JavaScript assign it to a div tag.